# Using additional methods correctly

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with additional "public static double" methods. The results I get are; for the first output, 1-10 in ascending order. The two other outputs I get are ten 0.0 results. My issue is not formatting, nor do I have any error messages.

Here is what I currently have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Sec\tMeters\tFeet ");

    for (int t=1; t<=10; t+=1) {
        System.out.print(t);

        System.out.print("\t" + distanceFell(t));

        double conv = ((1/2) * 9.8 * ((t)*(t)));
       System.out.println("\t" + metersToFeet(conv));
}

}           

public static double distanceFell(int t) 
{
    double conv = ((1/2) * 9.8 * ((t)*(t)));
    return (conv);
}

public static double metersToFeet (double conv) 
{
    double convFeet = (conv / 0.3048);
    return (convFeet);          
}
}
```

Comment: What problems **specifically** are you having? Is it converting doubles to Strings? Are you getting compiler error messages? Misbehaviors? Something else? The more specific and clear your question, usually the better the answers you'll see.

Comment: You don't have a variable `conv` which you want to use in `metersToFeet()`

Comment: I'm guessing that one of your problems is output formatting. At a minimum, you probably want to use `System.out.print(...)` instead of `System.out.println(...)` for the first two outputs in the loop. And also print a `"\t"` in between.

Comment: `t ^ 2` does not raise `t` to the power of 2.  Write `t * t`.

Comment: @QBrute - It's the argument to the method.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, in the **method definition**: `public static double metersToFeet(double conv)`. But when actually using it `System.out.println(metersToFeet(conv));` there's no `conv` variable defined...

Comment: @QBrute - Ah. I misinterpreted your comment, reading "in `metersToFeet()`" as referring to the implementation of the method, while you meant it to be read as "in the call to `metersToFeet()`". I should have looked in both places.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : One of the problems I have is "distanceFell(t)" displaying 0.0's and "metersToFeet(conv)" displays an error message that conv cannot be resolved to a variable. I'm guessing I have to make a "conv" variable in the main function for the last method to pull from.

Comment: Okay, thank you @john16384

Comment: Also `(1/2)` will always be 0 as your dividing an integer here.  If you want 0.5 then just type `0.5`

Comment: @john16384 You are my Savior, I changed that and my program works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are starting your multiplication with `1/2`, this gives a result of `0`.  Integer division keeps the whole segment of the division and throws out the remainder.

Thus you get `0 * 9.8 * t * t`, which is, as you've noticed, `0.0`.

Rather than `1/2`, you should try `0.5`.  This will give you the floating-point maths that you're after.

Comment: Works perfectly! I did not know that integer division throws out the remainder, thank you for your explanation.